# SQL Server - splitting multiple rows using STRING_SPLIT function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2016.

I have the following table

```
 [ID]    [Name List1]   [Name List2]        [Name List3]
 1       a1,a2,a3       a21,a22             a31,a32,a33,a34,a45
 2       b1,b2          b21,b22,b23,b24     b31
 3       etc....
```

[ID] is a unique identifier column.

I need to split all these comma delimited fields into separate records.

What I did so far:

```
SELECT a.*,  b.[Name List1] FROM  [TABLE1] a LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT [ID], value AS [Name List1]
FROM [TABLE1] CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([Name List1], ',')
WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND rtrim(value) <> '') b ON a.[ID]=b.[ID]
```

This query will split records based on the first column, i.e. [Name List1]
but I need to do it for all columns ([Name List2] and [Name List3] as well).

Is there an elegant way to achieve it with minimum coding?

Desired result should include all possible combinations of these comma delimited values:

```
 [ID]    [Name List1]   [Name List2]        [Name List3]
 1       a1             a21                 a31
 2       a2             a21                 a31
 3       a3             a21                 a31
 4     etc... meaning all possible combination of column splits
```

Comment: Maybe concatenate the lists together to be one big list and split that?

Comment: Please show the results that you want.  It is not obvious.

Comment: I still need the column headers to be the same. I shall post also the desired output

Comment: You desired result isn't clear. It looks like you just want the first item of each list  from the record with `id = 1` and replicate that for all `id`s. That doesn't match the rest of the question. Please take the effort and post an actual result, that matches the posted sample data.

Comment: `all possible combination of column splits` - that is simply three `cross apply` in a row. `[TABLE1] CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([Name List1], ',') l1 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([Name List2], ',') l2 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([Name List3], ',') l3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all possible combinations, use `STRING_SPLIT()` and three `CROSS APPLY` operators:

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   ID int,
   [Name List1] varchar(100),
   [Name List2] varchar(100),
   [Name List3] varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (ID, [Name List1], [Name List2], [Name List3])
VALUES   
   (1, 'a1,a2,a3', 'a21,a22',         'a31,a32,a33,a34,a45'),
   (2, 'b1,b2',    'b21,b22,b23,b24', 'b31')
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
   d.ID, 
   s1.[value] AS [Name List1],
   s2.[value] AS [Name List2],
   s3.[value] AS [Name List3]
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(d.[Name List1], ',') s1
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(d.[Name List2], ',') s2
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(d.[Name List3], ',') s3
```

Output:

```
ID  Name List1  Name List2  Name List3
1   a1          a21         a31
1   a1          a21         a32
1   a1          a21         a33
1   a1          a21         a34
1   a1          a21         a45
1   a1          a22         a31
1   a1          a22         a32
1   a1          a22         a33
1   a1          a22         a34
1   a1          a22         a45
…
```

If you want to get all possible combinations with positions of each substring , then `STRING_SPLIT()` is not an option here, because this function returns a table with all substrings, but they are not ordered and the order of substrings is not guaranteed. One option in this case is to transform text into valid `JSON` array using `REPLACE()` and after that to use `OPENJSON()` with default schema to retrieve this `JSON` array as table, which has columns `key`, `value` and `type` (`key` column contains the index of the element in the specified array).

T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
   d.ID, 
   j1.[key] + 1 AS [Key List1], j1.[value] AS [Name List1],
   j2.[key] + 1 AS [Key List2], j2.[value] AS [Name List2],
   j3.[key] + 1 AS [Key List3], j3.[value] AS [Name List3]
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(d.[Name List1], ',', '","') + '"]') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(d.[Name List2], ',', '","') + '"]') j2
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(d.[Name List3], ',', '","') + '"]') j3
```

Output:

```
ID  Key List1   Name List1  Key List2   Name List2  Key List3   Name List3
1   1           a1          1           a21         1           a31
1   1           a1          1           a21         2           a32
1   1           a1          1           a21         3           a33
1   1           a1          1           a21         4           a34
1   1           a1          1           a21         5           a45
1   1           a1          2           a22         1           a31
1   1           a1          2           a22         2           a32
1   1           a1          2           a22         3           a33
1   1           a1          2           a22         4           a34
1   1           a1          2           a22         5           a45
…
```

Comment: Thank you Zhorov for your detailed answer. Just realized though that I was not clear enough regarding the expected output. Let's put it this way: the query I posted, using STRING_SPLIT deals with the first column having CSV data. I can insert the result into a temporary table. Then I apply the same query to this temporary table but on the 2-nd column. Then again I repeat the process. The problem is that production table has 12 columns containing CSV strings and writing a stored procedure with repeating code is not an elegant solution. However... your code may achieve exactly the same thing?

Comment: @User123 Yes, If I understand you correctly. You'll achieve the same output if you execute one statement with `APPLY` operators for all 12 columns. And, of course, use `DISTINCT` if you want to get only unique combinations. Thanks.